Copy all sheets from all open workbooks
I have 4 open workbooks (and in general it should work with 10 open workbooks). The macro copies data only from the first two open ones, then

error 1004 "Method 'copy' of object_Worksheet' failed"

Sub AllInOne()
    Dim sW As Workbook
    Dim sS As Worksheet
    For Each sW In Workbooks
        For Each sS In sW.Sheets
            sS.Copy Before:=Workbooks("All.xlsm").Sheets(1)
        Next sS
    Next sW
End Sub


Try excluding Workbooks("All.xlsm") from workbooks iteration. Something as If sW.Name <> "All.xlsm" Then and enter in sequence of sheets iteration.

Add If sW.Name <> "All.xlsm" Then:
Dim sW As Workbook Dim sS As Worksheet For Each sW In Workbooks If sW.Name <> "All.xlsm" Then         For Each sS In sW.Sheets             sS.Copy Before:=Workbooks("All.xlsm").Sheets(1)         Next sS end if Next sW
but still have an error 1004

Then, it is good to check if the respective sheet/workbook where you try copying from, or the destination one are not protected or hidden. When stopped on error write Debug.Print ss.Name, sw.anme: Stop and comment the existing line. Then, press Ctrl + G to open Immediate Window and see its return, to check against I suggested before.

Files are not locked. I've tested the macro with only one file open at a time - it works. When 2+ files are open, it copies sheets only from the first one and it seems that it does not switch to the next book, or something like that.

Do you have any Excel add-in? Did you try what I suggested? If so, what did it return in Immediate Window? If not, why not? Also, try commenting the code lines related to worksheets iteration and only place a debugging line Debug.Print sW.Name. Does it return what you think it should be returned?

I added a only a debug.print sw.Name and it showed:
"Col
Stat
Inf" (all sheets name from all workbooks)
And now it woks somehow, ty

Did it show what?

Import Sheets

Note that even hidden workbooks are included i.e. if you're using PERSONAL.xlsb, its work(sheets) will also be imported.
Note that hidden sheets will be imported hidden, while very hidden sheets will raise an error.
Both issues can be resolved with simple If statements.
Be more careful how you use the Sheets and Worksheets collections. If you declare the variable As Worksheet, use the Worksheets collection. Similarly, if you want to use the Sheets collection (includes charts), declare the variable As Object.

Worksheets
Sub ImportWorksheets() ' charts are not imported
 
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks("All.xlsm")
    ' If this code is in 'All.xlsm', you don't need to specify its name.
    ' Instead use 'ThisWorkbook':
    'Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
    
    Dim swb As Workbook, sws As Worksheet
    
    For Each swb In Workbooks
        If Not swb Is dwb Then ' exclude the destination workbook
            For Each sws In swb.Worksheets
                sws.Copy Before:=dws
            Next sws
        End If
    Next swb
    
    MsgBox "Imported all worksheets from all open workbooks.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

Sheets
Sub ImportSheets() ' charts are also imported
 
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks("All.xlsm")
    ' If this code is in 'All.xlsm', you don't need to specify its name.
    ' Instead use 'ThisWorkbook':
    'Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim dsh As Object: Set dsh = dwb.Sheets(1) ' there is no 'Sheet' object
    
    Dim swb As Workbook, ssh As Object ' there is no 'Sheet' object
    
    For Each swb In Workbooks
        If Not swb Is dwb Then ' exclude the destination workbook
            For Each ssh In swb.Sheets
                ssh.Copy Before:=dsh
            Next ssh
        End If
    Next swb
    
    MsgBox "Imported all sheets from all open workbooks.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

